# ccnet running as a service cannot access networked drive

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

I'm trying to set up a legacy application in cruise control and ran into a bit of a problem.

I've set up my project and had to include a section where nant copies files from a local file path to a networked drive.

If I run force the build through the ccnet.exe command line it works fine. If I start the service and try to force the build through the front end it fails, saying:

```
  "Could not find a part of the path 'L:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite'."
```

But that location does exist. I've changed the service to use the user credentials I log onto the server with but still getting the same error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. The working directory of a CC.NET project is located on a linux machine accessible via samba with independant credentials. Service does not start at boot because the working dir can not be reached.
And I use the UNC format.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Typical, I spend hours trying to get to the bottom of this and then 10 minutes after asking the question I solve it.

The problem is when a service uses a username it creates an isolated login session. The network drives belong to the interactive session, and therefore the service's isolated session does not have access to them.

The solution was to move away from using a networked drive and use the UNC instead. I had been told this worked previously with networked drives, but I think they were being mapped every time the ccnet tried a build.